# I want to execute command of cmd.exe through php but in cmd it is executing but in php exec() it is not executing

Tags: php, cmd, command

I want execute this command but it is not scheduling the task, but this same command executed in cmd.

```
echo exec('schtasks /create /np /sc minute /mo 1 /tn "TestRail Background Task" /tr "\"start http://localhost/cronjob2/cronjob.php""
');
```

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: @yogesh What error message are you getting? Are you running as Administrator? `schtasks` needs to be with Administrator permissions.

Comment: @AmitShah it is Windows

Comment: yes it is windows7 32bit

Comment: @Amnon showing me error Array ( [0] => ERROR: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done. [1] => (45,4):LogonType: )

Comment: Looks like a permissions issue. Is the user running `php` an Admin of the machine?

Comment: @Amnon how to give permission? did you know?

Comment: Use Windows Control Panel. I do not, however, think you should run your webapp as root. It is a security breach.

Comment: @Amnon Thanks I solved this prob.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by giving /RU system in command it executed

$command = 'schtasks /create /np /sc minute /mo 1 /tn "cronjob2" /tr "\"D:\www\webroot\cronjob2\shellscript.vbs"" /RU System';
exec("$command 2>&1", $output);
print_r($output);